# Finding the least prime of the form $6^{6^6}+k$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, math-software

I try to find the least prime number of the form $6^{6^6}+k$. I sieved out the
 candidates by trial division upto $10^6$, but there are still many candidates
 left upto $k=10000$

- How can I further reduce the number of candidates ?
- Where can I download a FAST calculator able to check numbers of this
  magnitude ($36306$ digits) ? PARI can do this, but takes about $10$ minutes
  which is too much considering the number of tests probably required.

  I do not want to prove the number to be prime. I am content if the number is pseudoprime
  for base $2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By examining [A103111](http://oeis.org/A103111) you can see that $k=96545,$ found by the late Donovan Johnson in 2008. Otherwise srsieve and pfgw are a pretty good combination.